# Alternative for Schwalbe Kojak 35-584 tire

Tags: tire

I bought a Canyon Commuter 7.0 bike. It has 27.5 inch DT SWISS XR331 rims and Kojak 35-584 tires. It seems as if Schwalbe is the only manufacturer having a 35-584 sport tire. Do you know of any alternative for this tire that will fit my wheels?

Comment: Did you try a search engine? I found several tyres that size: https://www.google.com/search?q=35-584+tyre and https://duckduckgo.com/?q=35-584

Comment: Yes, I did. But the found tires do not meet the requirement of being sport tires. They are mostly targeted to MTBs. Also color is important. E.g. the Michelin WorldTour 650B is a creme and black tire having a vintage look that does not go well with the Commuter.

Comment: Velo Orange, Rivendell Cycles and Compass Cycles all have a selection of interesting road versions of 650B tires.

Comment: Curiously, despite looking really fast, these tyres have an incredibly poor rating on https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/tour-reviews/schwalbe-kojak-2017  so they have relatively high rolling resistance.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to replace the tire with a tire that is exactly the same ERTRO. And while ERTRO's are probably the most accurate tire measurement, they still aren't all that accurate. One manufacturers 35-584 can be slightly wider/narrower than another's.

See http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html

Unless the bike has very tight clearances ( unlikely for a Commuter bike) you should be able to use any tire in the range 30-584 to 40-584 ( or even larger). The only important number in the ERTRO designation is the rim size (i.e the second number).

Panaracer makes some good relatively cheap 650B ( or *-584) tires[1] that would likely work well on that bike if you don't want to stick with Schwalbe. Schwalbe has a pretty nice range of 650B tires in "road" widths.

If you search for 650B Road tires, you should get a pretty good selection of tires that will work for your bike.

[1]- Col de la Vie or Pasela.

Comment: You can also search a bit more easily or in shops by asking for a 650B tire of the appropriate number of mm.

Comment: @Batman US shops, maybe, here that's likely to be met with "don't you mean 700c" because the kids these days only know metric sizing and the latest marketing terms.

Comment: @Móż - In the US, I don't think most shops will carry non-mountain 650B tires (if they even carry that size, which they likely don't). But, I suppose if you know every description of the size, you'll eventually get one that works.

Comment: @Batman I strongly suspect most shops in Oz would have to order them too, barring a few commuter/ebike shops. 10 years ago when I had a bike with those tyres that was the case. I chopped that bike up and made it into  something more useful, because the tyres were a PITA to get hold of. But asking for "650B" got me blank looks, 32-584 got me someone who knew about tyres and understood the question :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same bike. Ended up going with Panaracer Gravelking 27.5 x 1.50 (38-584) here in Japan